# Trying to get average (mean) color of canvas vs slices thereof. getting inaccurate results

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to get the mean color of an image, to compare to the mean color of various slices of the image, to find the area that is most different from the mean.  it's part of a project to crop an image automatically, based on areas of greatest interest.

I was getting strange results, so I created a demo page that compares a totally flat red image with slices thereof.  each slice should have the same color as the image (192,0,0,255).  but, as you can see, they don't:

http://gschoppe.com/projects/jQuery.smartCrop/demo.html  (all data goes to the console)

Here's the average color function from the demo:

```
var getAverageColor = function(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgdata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixels  = imgdata.data;
    var color   = {red:0,green:0,blue:0,alpha:0};
    // Loop over each pixel.
    for (var i = 0, n = pixels.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        color.red   += pixels[i  ]/255; //red
        color.green += pixels[i+1]/255; //green
        color.blue  += pixels[i+2]/255; //blue
        color.alpha += pixels[i+3]/255; //alpha
    }
    color.red   = color.red/(pixels.length/4);
    color.green = color.green/(pixels.length/4);
    color.blue  = color.blue/(pixels.length/4);
    color.alpha = color.alpha/(pixels.length/4);
    return color;
}
```

and here's the (simplified) version of the loop where it's called:

```
var findPointOfInterest = function(canvas) {
    var sliceSize     = Math.round(canvas.width/20);
    var avgColor      = getAverageColor(canvas);
    console.log("avg color: ");
    console.log(avgColor);
    var sliceColor    = null;
    for(var i=0;i<canvas.width;i+=sliceSize) {
        if(i+sliceSize > canvas.width)
            sliceSize = canvas.width % sliceSize;
        var temp      = document.createElement('canvas');
        temp.width    = sliceSize;
        temp.height   = canvas.height;
        var context   = temp.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect ( 0, 0, sliceSize, canvas.height );
        context.drawImage(canvas, i, 0, sliceSize, canvas.height, 0, 0, sliceSize, canvas.height);
        sliceColor    = getAverageColor(temp);
        console.log(sliceColor);
    }
}
```

I made a simpler version of the issue for JSFiddle, but it doesn't seem to have the bug! GAH!  Here's the simple version: http://jsfiddle.net/tLMPk/  (everything logs to the console)

can anyone help me track this thing down?

Comment: when you say 'crop', you mean crop once (the borders) or crop into several images ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist The end goal is to crop the borders of an IMG tag, using the CSS clip property.  That way, you can present a user-uploaded image in a responsive layout, in such a way that the interesting parts of the image will always be included.  The test code I uploaded doesn't do that part yet, it's just supposed to identify how interesting each chunk of the image is.
If it helps, here's a version of the same algorithm that I wrote in PHP a couple weeks ago: http://pastebin.com/zdMaPSgr

Comment: ok. So i must admit i don't understand at all your way of doing this. The way i would do it would be to scan hlines and vlines as long as they have the same color as point(0,0) to decide how much i should remove on left/right/top/bottom. But i might be missing a point here...

Comment: @GameAlchemist that sounds like you're looking to remove borders.  I'm looking to make arbitrary images fit in a fixed set of dimensions.  I'm making an algorithm similar to this: http://codegeekz.com/cropping-images-entrop/

Comment: ok. Your simple version is working ok : for a red filled canvas, it always return red = 1.0... no issue (you normalize the red in your loop (/255)), and if half filled, it return what's expected : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/tLMPk/3/  Notice that both for a huge performance boost and for readability you should getImageData only once and use something like the third method i mention here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24699870/856501

Comment: Yeah, I'll be optimizing to a single canvas solution once I have it working properly.  This is just a proof of concept, and I wanted to be able to write each step to the DOM for visual inspection.  I actually found that my problem was due to not realizing that objects are passed by reference.  My color normalization function was modifying the color objects.